# how to use jquery ui full files rather minified versions?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have implemented datepicker following "[jQuery getting started](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started)", using 3 files:

1. `<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />`
2. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`
3. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>`

It suggests to use 3 files including "jquery-1.4.4.min.js". What if I want to use full .js file e.g "jquery.ui.datepicker.js" for datepicker. Reason of asking to use full version is to modify some elements for my need which is difficult in minified version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then download and reference the unminified version.

There is no difference aside from the size of the files. You can always re-minify once you've completed your changes.

If you're doing a custom build, the non minified version of `jquery.ui.datepicker` will be in in the `development-bundle/ui` folder.

Comment: Thanks Brandon! Does that mean simply replacing minified version with full version. I tried once, but it didn't pickup the calendar. Anything further to look at?

Comment: It means that when you use a minified version, the file name usually has `.min` in it, while the unminified version doesn't. So make sure you're pointing to the correct file in your `<script src`

Comment: One more thing I did to get this working was that "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.js" should be used instead of "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" apart from "jquery.ui.datepicker.js".